# Functional programming in java: Cloning Vs Mutating. Good or bad?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, immutability

**Mutating:**

"transformEmployeeNameToUpperCase" function to transform employee name to uppercase.

```
List<Employee> employeesStartsWithDInUppercase1 = employees.stream()
            .filter(employee -> employee.getName().startsWith("D"))
            .map(Main::transformEmployeeNameToUpperCase)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

public static Employee transformEmployeeNameToUpperCase(Employee employee){
    employee.setName(employee.getName().toUpperCase());
    return employee;
}
```

**Cloning:**

"createEmployeeWithUpperCaseName" function to new employee with name in uppercase.

```
List<Employee> employeesStartsWithDInUppercase2 = employees.stream()
            .filter(employee -> employee.getName().startsWith("D"))
            .map(Main::createEmployeeWithUpperCaseName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


public static Employee createEmployeeWithUpperCaseName(Employee e){
    return new Employee( e.getId(), e.getName().toUpperCase(), e.getDesignation(), e.getAge());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does "createEmployeeWithUpperCaseName" follow rule 1(above) as they say

yes: the employee is not being modified

> In case of "transformEmployeeNameToUpperCase", does it follow rule 2(above)?

yes, although the rule uses an incorrect terminology. It creates an object, not a variable. You can't create a variable.

> Is it good practice to use transformEmployeeNameToUpperCase way?

No, at least not the way you're doing it. There's nothing bad per se in modifying mutable objects: they're mutable for a reason. But a `map()` operation shouldn't modify its input and return it. You're perverting its purpose. A future reader of your code wouldn't expect a map operation to mutate its input, and you're thus making your code do unexpected things, leading to bugs and/or misunderstandings. It would be better to do it this way:

```
employees.stream()
         .filter(employee -> employee.getName().startsWith("D"))
         .forEach(e -> e.setName(e.getName().toUpperCase()));
```

That way, it makes it clear that the point of the pipeline is to have a side effect on the elements of the list. And it doesn't create a (probably) useless copy of the list, too.

Comment: employees.stream()
         .filter(employee -> employee.getName().startsWith("D"))
         .forEach(e -> e.setName(e.getName().toUpperCase()));

Applying forEach after filter, isn't it contradictory to rule 2(above)? as I can see it is modifying actual list.

Comment: Where did I say it respected rule 2? It doesn't. My point is that a foreach make it clear that the whole point is to modify the employees in the list. Whereas a map() indicates the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @JB Nizet, but still if you don't want to change the original object but want to change the name of employee to Uppercase. use object cloning.

pseudo code:

```
List<Employee> employeeWithUpperCaseName = employees.parallelStream()
                .filter(e -> e.getName().startsWith("D"))
                .map(x -> {
                    Employee s = null;
                    try {
                        s = (Employee) x.clone();
                        s.setName(x.getName().toUpperCase());
                    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        return s;
                    }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you can write it in better way.

Comment: This is unreadable, better would be a method and also returning null is probably a really bad idea

Comment: @Lino this is just an alternative, though we can write this in managed and clean way. Just for the simplicity i posted it.that why I written pseudo code.

Comment: @Lino  How about filtering "null" after map in above example given by Sahil varma and then collecting it?

Comment: Who said that `Employee` has a `public` clone method?

Comment: Hi @Holger, it’s pretty obvious if you are cloning a class object, then we have to ensure this.